# JPA - Save element when parent exist in ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have two entities, Branch and Enterprise, the two entities extends of a AbstractEntity

AbstractEntity

```
@Id
@Column(length=36)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

Branch entity:

```
private String name;
private int code;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id")
private Enterprise enterprise;
```

Enterprise entity

```
private String name;
private String nit;
private String sheetconfig;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy = "enterprise", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
```

When i try to save a branch, i select the enterprise in a combobox and send the request but i get the follow error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.gettecob.gestcart.model.Branch.enterprise
```

NOTE: The enterprises list exist, only i need save the branch whit the enterprise assoc.

The bean config:

```
 @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.gettecob.gestcart.*"});
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

The BranchRepository save method

```
public Branch save(Branch branch) {
    return em.merge(branch);
}
```

I need help whit this.

Comment: Has enterprise have the id set?

Comment: @ThomasEdwin yes, the enterprise object have the id field set.

Comment: Try persisting the Enterprise first and then the Branch entity. - Assuming the enterprise is not present in the database and if it is present and the same entity is set to Branch entity while persisting then we need to dig deeper. May be the persisting code and the setting might help identifying the issue.

Comment: I meant the setting as in how you are constructing the branch object. Like below..

Comment: branch = new Branch();
    branch.setId("abc");
    branch.setEnterprise(enterprise):
    dao.save(branch);

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `Enterprise` is unmanaged is not clear to me. It might be not persisted at all or it might be detached or obtained from some other persistence context.

It can happen for example if you set the `id` of the new entity to imitate existing entity since persistence context should handle setting `id`.

If it is not persisted before then in order to have `Enterprise` persisted when persisting `Branch` you need to enable `CascadeType.PERSIST` in its `@ManyToOne` annotation

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id")
private Enterprise enterprise;
```

You can try also to enable `CascadeType.MERGE`. It depends a bit on what reason your `Enterprise` is considered as *detached*.